# Date Format Change in Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using PHP JSON as API in android. I am taking news from MYSQL data with below code. Its working fine but date format is showing as **YYYY-MM-DD.** But I want get it like **DD-MM-YYYY.** I have searched lot of but not found any solution. Can anybody here can solve my issue ?

```html
<?php
$response = array();
require 'db.php';

 $query = "SELECT * FROM news where order by id desc";
 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        
    $response["news"] = array();
    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             
            $news= array();
            $news["id"] = $row["id"]; 
            $news["title"] = $row["title"];       
            $news["description"] = $row["description"];                
            $news["news_date"] = $row["news_date"]; 
          array_push($response["news"], $news);
          }
           $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    //echo json_encode($response);
    echo json_encode($response['news']);
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
   $news["news_date"] = date("d-m-Y" ,strtotime  ($row["news_date"]) );
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and given me result which I need. Thanks a lot boss. You are great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your SQL a bit to format the date to DD-MM-YYYY using `date_format()` like this:

```
select
    id,
    title,
    description,
    date_format(news_date,'%d-%m-%Y') news_date
from 
    news
order by
    id desc;
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for nice suggestion but its giving me error like "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in myroot/getNews.php on line 10
{"success":0} and line 10 is if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {